# How to create throw exception function that its parent function do not throw any error

Tags: java, inheritance, error-handling, stack

I am creating a fixed sized stack, when trying to push a new element while the stack is already reached the limits, the push function shall throw an exception to notify the limits has reached, please see the code spinet below

```
public class SizedStack<T> extends Stack<T> {
  private int maxSize;

  public SizedStack(int size) {
    super();
    this.maxSize = size;
  }

  @Override
  public T push(T object) throws Exception{ // error message for the exception throwing 
    //If the stack is too big, return an Exception 
    while (this.size() > maxSize) {
      throw new Exception("Stack Overflow");
    }
    return super.push(object);
  }
}
```

Issues: the `push` function from the parent `stack` class do not return any exceptions. Therefore I get an error for my code.

```
Exception is not compatible with throws clause in Stack<t>.push(T);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Just throw a RuntimeException (or rather a subclass)

Comment: The problem is `push` is inherited from the superclass `Stack` and does not throw an exception there. Adding a checked exception to a inherited method is illegal since it violates polymorphism. You either need to give up on the inheritance or throw an unchecked exception